# Varying Line Width in Drop Down Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, drop-down-menu

How do you create varying line heights using CSS in a drop down menu? As you can see below, I am changing the font sizes of each element, however, the new font is not being applied once selected. Thanks!

```
<select>
        <option class="w1">&#9472&#9472&#9472&#9472</option>
        <option class="w2">&#9472&#9472&#9472&#9472</option>
</select>

option.w1  {
  font-size: 5px;
}
option.w2  {
  font-size:8px;  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kwham1bf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to select an element's parent using CSS. In this case, the parent is the `select` and the child is the selected `option`.

If you need to style the `select` based on the selected `option`, you'll have to resort to using JavaScript:

```js
var select = document.querySelector("select");

select.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var selected = document.querySelector("option:checked");
    var selectedFontSize = getComputedStyle(selected, null).getPropertyValue("font-size");
    select.style.fontSize = selectedFontSize;
});
```

```css
option.w1  {
  font-size: 5px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
  
}

option.w2  {
  font-size:8px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
}

option.w3 {
  font-size: 11px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
}

option.w4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
}

option.w5 {
  font-size: 17px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
}

option.w6 {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<div class="row add-top-margin">
  <div class="col-xs-3 section-label">Width</div>
  <select>
    <option class="w1">&#9472&#9472&#9472&#9472</option>
    <option class="w2">&#9472&#9472&#9472&#9472</option>
    <option class="w3">&#9472&#9472&#9472&#9472</option>
    <option class="w4">&#9472&#9472&#9472&#9472</option>
    <option class="w5">&#9472&#9472&#9472&#9472</option>
    <option class="w6">&#9472&#9472&#9472&#9472</option>
  </select> 
</div>
```